# Chakra UI dark mode persist on one browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, chakra-ui, darkmode

Recently i was working on implementing chakra ui's dark mode in one of my nextjs app, i did that successfully and i was running the dev server on port "3000" and seeing the design on "google chorme".

Next day when i was working on my "another" project in which there is no mention or intention of dark mode in my codebase, the default color scheme was "dark" out of nowhere

#### Elements in Chrome

[image: html elements screenshot]

So, I switched to another browser (edge) and the components were as expected i.e. in "light" mode. How do i prevent this thing from happening?

##### In Google Chrome

[image: google chorme screenshot]

##### Simultaneously in Microsoft Edge

[image: edge browser screenshot]

### Cause

I think the problem is caused by ports not getting kill properly OR localstorage(chakra ui uses localstorage for saving the current theme) data not cleaned